# Dead code removal from switch cases in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, google-closure-compiler, yui-compressor

Does any compressor take care of removing the switch cases which do not get called anywhere in the application?

```
function execute_case(id) {
    switch(id) {
    case 0:
       console.log("0");
       break;
    case 1:
       console.log("1");
       break;
    case 2:
       console.log("2");
       break;
    case 3:
       console.log("3");
       break;
    default:
       console.log("default");
       break;
    }
}

execute_case(1);
```

If the above is all I have, then theoretically cases 0,2,3 are dead code and will never be executed. Does any compressor have the intelligence of removing this code when minifying code?

I am taking a look at a piece of code which has over 200,000 cases in a switch statement, and hence the question.

Thanks,
-Vikrant

Comment: for that you have to get your hands dirty with garbage collection stuff.i would say..just enjoy your coding

Comment: I hesitate to ask, but, 200K case statements? WTF?

Comment: There's no way for the compiler to know that the line at the bottom is the only place where the function will ever be called. You might load some other JS file later, and it could have a call to the function, with a different parameter.

Comment: Instead of such a huge case statement, you should make a dispatch table using an array of functions. However, it's possible that the compiler will implement the case statement by translating it into a dispatch table.

Comment: Something has gone horribly wrong if you've got code with 200,000 cases in a switch statement, and no compressor is going to fix that.

Comment: Silly me, here I thought dead code was `if (x) { /*..*/} else if (!x) {/*..*/} else {/* this stuff */ }`

Comment: well, 200K it is.. I know, i was shocked too! this is basically some code which defines any constant that can exist in the system depending on which object wants it. I am sure, that the invocations are direct numbers.. no variables.. no math.. so either i could manually grep and isolate the cases which aren't getting used!! but then i would always have to add them back manually if we started using them tomorrow.. and hence this question came to my mind. If minifier took care of this, may be with a param case (--I_TAKE_FULL_RESPONSIBILITY), then it would autocorrect itself later.

Comment: @Pointy: I've got a one-line compressor function that should help with that: `var compressor = function(sourceCode) {return "throw new SyntaxError('Code too long.');"}`

Comment: @Barmar - speaking from a pure minification perspective, converting it into a dispatch table using an array of functions also might not remove any code which isn't used. We will have the same problem with the array indexes. What is the recommended way of dealing with these cases, purely from a minification perspective.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about minification, more about optimizing the execution so it's not done as a series of thousands of `if/elseif` tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Sir,

As `id` is a variable, no compressor will "know" that this can not happen.  The compressors do not analyze variable values in switch statements and know how to remove them.

If you "know" these cases will not happen, just remove them yourself.

Comment: indeed, way too many "what-ifs" to guarantee a case won't be hit (what if it's passed a variable, what if that variable came from an AJAX call, what if there was math involved, what if...)

Comment: I think he's expecting the compiler to notice that the function is only called from one place, and that place has a constant parameter, so it can do constant propagation into the function definition.

Comment: The OP is intelligent, as such he expects too much of the compressor.

Comment: @Barmar: But in a dynamic language, that's pretty hard to guarantee.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I didn't say the expectation was reasonable. :)

Comment: @Barmar - speaking from a pure minification perspective, converting it into a dispatch table using an array of functions also might not remove any code which isn't used. We will have the same problem with the array indexes. What is the recommended way of dealing with these cases, purely from a minification perspective.

Comment: While the current answer is "no" it is certainly within the realm of possibility for Closure-compiler using ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS. Closure-compiler is fully optimizing compiler and does similar analysis for other dead code removal.

Comment: Closure already removes dead code from unreachable ifs. There's no reason why it couldn't do the same with switches. And "compressors do not analyze variable values" is simply not true.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is going to definitively give you a list of dead case statements. If it says it can there is either no possibility of another value (finite code branching) or it's lying. So unless you know every possible value that can be passed to `execute_case`, you'll be in the dark. (And I assume you don't given the question).

What you *can* do is place a small logger in that code that outputs/records the values being passed to that switch. Then, over [a good amount of] time and/or several thousand executions, track which ones are being hit and which ones aren't. I wouldn't necessarily remove ones not being hit, but maybe try deprecating them and wait for a longer duration/more executions until you reach the conclusion it's no longer necessary.

Comment: well, in this case, I have a way to find all the possible calls. No dynamic calls here. All are direct invocations with the switch ID explicitly being a number. So, it will cost me a grep | uniq to get all the valid cases. But the set is still very large (200K) to manually remove. and also there is the danger that if something case which is unused today gets used tomorrow because of something new that we add, then we will have to re-do it. minifier would have taken care of all of that out. may be minifier with a special case (--strict_case_minification for such cases)